# Spring Security Saml two sp

Tags: security, saml, adfs

I Config "Spring Security Saml" for SSO Login from ADFS .
It work on one sp(domain)_(ex. https://test.domain.v/s-s-s/) but when I run another sp :

1. Global logout not work,
2. When login with one of the sp , another session removed and again checking required .

Please help me to fix this problems .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Global Logout not Working Again By runnig Spring Security Saml , but when 1 of the sp is Spring Security Saml and 2nd is other system (ex. share point) it's perfectly work

2.The cookie Save For domain name , by changing domain for 2nd sp , this work fine ...